# electron : how make an auto-update with squirrel on Windows?

Tags: windows, electron, squirrel.windows

With electron on widows I want to launch an auto-update when needed.
I want to use squirell and not electron-updater .
Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you probably don't need to use electron-updater. You can build your app with Squirrel by using `electron-packager`: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager

Then, you could use build-in module `autoUpdater`(electron's doc [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/auto-updater)) to make auto updater.

Comment: Can you use this to have a local source for the updates? If you want to have the new releases posted to a common network drive to avoid having an update server?